# Intel dual band wireless 7260 not working on Kali Linux

Tags: linux, wifi, kali-linux, backtrack, iwlwifi

i have installed Kali-Linux in virtual box, but i am struggling to make my wifi work for almost 3-4 days. i have tried few things, out of which best options are listed below :

https://askubuntu.com/questions/331667/no-wireless-for-intel-corporation-7260-version-63

https://askubuntu.com/questions/433539/intel-7260-works-during-installation-but-not-after-reboot

But nothing is working for me, i cannot see my wifi card in iwconfig.

Comment: As Kali is running in a VM, try to get Virtual Box connect to the internet. BTW if you have any plan installing Kali on real hardware, try installing package `firmware-iwlwifi`.

Comment: I have installed firmware-iwlwifi and copied the .ucode file also, but its still not working :-( and i think the .ucode version is also correct.

Comment: No, the firmware only work on real machine, for networking in VirtualBox try this instead: https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html

Comment: I am able to access the internet in the linux, but the problem is wifi is not working

Answer (score -2):

Not sure if it's going to work for you,  but I was able to connect the card to a Kali VM through Vmware Direct I/O passthrough.
I'm using an Esxi 6.5, which is running my Kali.